# Error Compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12 Module)

Tags: firebase, arduino, sensors, nodemcu, arduino-ultra-sonic

I have an issue connecting my NodeMCU v3 to the Arduino IDE. I have done the same code with the Arduino UNO (without the firebase part) connected to the ultrasonic sensor and there was no issue, but when trying to connect the NodeMCU v3 to the ultrasonic sensor I get this error.

What I'm trying to do is collect the data from the sensor and store it to the firebase while using the NodeMCU v3 ... which I keep having issues with.

This is my NodeMCU settings in Arduino IDE:

> Board: NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)
>   Upload speed: 115200
>   CPU freq: 80 MHz
>   flash size: 4m(no spiffs)
>   Debug port: disabled
>   Debug level: none
>   Iwlp variant: v2 lower memory 
>   VTables: flash
>   exceptions: enabled
>   Erase flash: only sketch
>   Port: Com6

```
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>     //wifi library
#define WIFI_SSID "wifi001"  //replace SSID with your wifi username
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "1234" //replace PWD with your wifi password
#define WIFI_LED D5          //connect a led to any of the gpio pins of the board and replace pin_number with it eg. D4
#define FIREBASE_HOST "some_firebase_host" //link of api
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "secret"             //database secret

int trig = 8;
int echo = 7;

long microsecondsToInches(float microseconds)
{
    return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(float microseconds)
{
    return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(WIFI_LED, OUTPUT); //define pinmodes
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    //connect to wifi
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    { //wait till connected to WiFi
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(WIFI_LED, LOW); //Blink the light till connected to WiFi
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(WIFI_LED, HIGH);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    digitalWrite(WIFI_LED, HIGH);
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH); //connect to Database
    pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echo, INPUT);

    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
    String firebaseResult = firebaseGet();
    delay(100);

    // Transmitting pulse
    digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trig, LOW);

    float t = 0, h = 0, hp = 0, inches = 0, cm = 0, offset = 1.8;

    if (firebaseResult == "ON")
    {
        //code to happen if the status is ON

        // Waiting for pulse
        t = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);

        // Calculating distance

        h = t;
        hp = h;
        h = t / offset; //half the bottle (16)
        h = h - 7;      // water height, 0 - 50 cm   - 0-16cm
                        //
        hp = (2 * h);   // distance in %, 0-100 %

        cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(hp);
        Serial.print(cm);
        Serial.print("\n");

        delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        //code to happen if the status is OFF
    }
}
```

The error that show is:

```
Arduino: 1.8.8 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Enabled, 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=enabled,eesz=4M,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=115200 -ide-version=10808 -build-path C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_989711 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_309203 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -verbose C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\level_meter\mustwork\now\now.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=enabled,eesz=4M,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=115200 -ide-version=10808 -build-path C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_989711 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_309203 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -verbose C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\level_meter\mustwork\now\now.ino
Using board 'nodemcuv2' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0-beta2
Using core 'esp8266' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0-beta2
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_989711/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fexceptions -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU\"" -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2\\variants\\nodemcu" "C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_989711\\sketch\\now.ino.cpp" -o nul
"C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_989711/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fexceptions -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU\"" -DESP8266 "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2\\cores\\esp8266" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.5.0-beta2\\variants\\nodemcu" "-IC:\\Users\\Elias\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\firebase-arduino-master\\src" "C:\\Users\\Elias\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_989711\\sketch\\now.ino.cpp" -o nul
In file included from C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/FirebaseArduino.h:22:0,

                 from C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\level_meter\mustwork\now\now.ino:1:

C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/Firebase.h:26:25: fatal error: ArduinoJson.h: No such file or directory

 #include <ArduinoJson.h>

                         ^

compilation terminated.

Using library firebase-arduino-master at version 0.1 in folder: C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
Invalid library found in C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\teckel12-arduino-new-ping-2ebf391d9be2: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\teckel12-arduino-new-ping-2ebf391d9be2
Invalid library found in C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\teckel12-arduino-new-ping-2ebf391d9be2: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Users\Elias\Documents\Arduino\libraries\teckel12-arduino-new-ping-2ebf391d9be2
```

Comment: Include the error in the question and you should remove your firebase credentials.

Comment: @blt I have edited and added the error...

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Arduino libraries need the ArduinoJson library installed. This can be done using the Library Manager to install it (find it in the `Tools` menu).

Firebase Arduino also needs an older version of Arduino Json e.g. 5.13.1 and is not compatible with newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar error, started working again after closing and re-opening the Arduino IDE and re-plugging in the Arduino.